# You have an error in your SQL syntax when adding query to the mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add an addon to my game here, and i need to add this query to the mysql, query is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `streets` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `min_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `text` longtext NOT NULL,
 `query` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO `settings` (`conf_id`, `conf_name`, `conf_value`) VALUES ('NULL', 'steps_daily', '100')

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `steps` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ;
```

When i try to enter the query into sql i get this error:

```
Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO  `settings` (  `conf_id` ,  `conf_name` ,  `conf_value` ) 
VALUES (

'NULL',  'steps_daily',  '100'
)
ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD  `steps` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `steps` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL' at line 3
```

Comment: `NULL` should not be in quotes.  You want the *value* `NULL`, not the *literall string* ,`'NULL'`.

Comment: Put a semi-colon at the end of your `INSERT` statement. Also, lose the single quotes around the `NULL` you're inserting into `conf_id`.

Comment: You haven't closed off the INSERT statement with a semicolon. Apologies if that just got missed in the copy and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `;` after your `INSERT INTO` query.

```
CREATE TABLE `streets` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `min_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `text` longtext NOT NULL,
 `query` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO `settings` (`conf_id`, `conf_name`, `conf_value`) VALUES
    (NULL, 'steps_daily', '100');

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `steps` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ;
```

P.S.: `NULL` should not be in quotes.  You want the *value* `NULL`, not the *literall string* ,`'NULL'`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use quotes for NULL and then try.

```
INSERT INTO  `settings` (  `conf_id` ,  `conf_name` ,  `conf_value` ) 
VALUES (NULL,  'steps_daily',  '100');
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause an error, or well, it wouldn't cause *this* error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat:- Do correct me if I am wrong but if conf_id(whose datatype is not given by OP) is int then can we insert 'NULL' or it should be NULL????

Comment: I was just pointing out that the `NULL` vs `'NULL` thing wasn't the cause of the error the OP asked about.  The cause was the lack of `;`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat:- Got that but that I had already taken that in my answer. It was just that I didnt pointed that and hence didnt got any vote!!! :(